# Font won't display in header for php include

Tags: php, html, css, apache, .htaccess

[image: Screen shot of the page, include file above, without is below]![

```html
<div id = "headz">
<div class = "titlez">
<h1>Developing Software by Delacrank</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

][Screen Shot PhP and after]

```css
.titlez {
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-size: xx-large;
    color: darkgreen;
    background-color: lightcyan;
}

#headz{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -2em;
    margin-right: -2em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
 charset=utf-8" />
<title>Our first Website (Lists, Definitions and Tables)</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      type = "text/css"
      href="testcss.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php include('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/includes/header.php'); ?>
```

Recently I decided to start using php to organize my website which consists of html files.  Currently, I am using xampp which comes with an apache server.  I added a .htaccess file to my server ('AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html') so that it can use the php scripts in my html files.

Everything seems fine, the problem is that when I add files from my includes folder the css styles which are linked to the html page work fine, except for the fonts. . .  I am not using any special fonts, the only font which displays seems to be courier by default, it won't display fantasy, times, arial, etc.

Am I missing something, please help.

I added the css file to the htdocs folder, its obviously locating it because the other styles work fine.  The includes file is in /applications/xampp/xamppfiles/htdocs/includes/.

I added a screen shot of the code, above is the include php, below is the same code without the php.  Everything is the same the only difference is the size of the font as well as the font family and font color, so nothing in the font is changed.

Comment: Hi, can you please show your css and tell us how your architecture is like? Where are your CSS files, your fonts, etc.

Comment: include your css. Was it displaying before php implementation? If anything, you can install the fonts on the server but times, arial, etc are default fonts which is included by default; most likely there is an issue in your stylesheet.

Comment: I've never done this before it is my first time, i didn't know you had to create a font folder, I will look into this.  Yeah, i was thinking I wouldn't need to create a font folder for default fonts.

Comment: You wrote `font-family: fantasy;`, so where is fantasy font family? I think this font is missing, not linked. The code is of course not working so maybe two screenshot would help (with and without php).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  Turns out it was something very simple, I added <h1> tags when they didn't need to be added. meh.